# AllenNLP SRL: Is it possible to get sense info for a lemma?

Tags: nlp, allennlp

I'm using AllenNLP for SRL, but the output doesn't provide role information / frame info / lemmas for the verb. All of that would be helpful.

I see that this information seems to exist here: [on the models github](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/ef5d4229f62f3ea8f44345d43b6a7fd1ab2d09fa/allennlp_models/common/ontonotes.py#L255), but I'm not sure if it's accessible for use with the latest/best SRL models that I believe use BERT.

Would it be possible to get the sense, frame, and lemma information alongside the SRL parse, using the state-of-the-art? If so, how is it done?